# How to display elevation points from point layer as in 3 different group/classes in qgis?

Tags: qgis, point

I have downloaded my elevation points from website Natural earth data (at a scale 10 Million), I wanted to display my elevation points like this in 3 classes:

**1) Elevation points, symbol('+') and name of elevations (with Label)**

**2) Elevation points, symbol('+') (without label)**

**3) Depression, symbol('-') (without label)**

I've tried them as in *rule-based* in "Style" and "Label" (see please screenshot),

*Properties > Style*
[image]

*Properties > Label*

[image]

*Depression (supposed to show only '-32' not with symbol'+') [is just one of an example]*

[image]

but it doesn't show me on the map correctly, how to classify them into 3 different group (as I mentioned above)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should specify an expression in 'Rule' section like `"elev_hoel" > 0`.

These expressions are similar example for styling:

[image]

For  labelling, an expression in 'Rule', preferably same expression in styling, and text format you want in 'Text' section.

[image]

Depending on field type, you may need to use/remove `to_int` and `to_string`.

Comment: Hi Kadir, Thanks for your replying! Which one (both?--"elevation" which is with name and "elevation2" without name/label) shall I change to "elevation_hoel >0"? and why (elevation_hoel >0)? because in my screenshots first and second, the first rule is with name, the second rule is without a name, third is depression. 2. depression: the red line is the symbol?

Comment: These are just similar examples. I don't have your data, so that, it's hard to write perfect solution for your problem. `"elevation" ` and `featurecla` are field names as shown in first figure (look at the attribute table). `double quote` is optional for field name. `featurecla` equals `"featurecla"`. First figure is for styling, second is for labelling. (please hit F7 key to view "Layer styling" panel. By this panel you see instantly changes you made)